# WPF menuitem shortcut. Strange behaviour

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

I create a menu item (context menu if that is of any help) using:

```
MenuItem menExit = new MenuItem();
menExit.Header = "Exit"; // will be changed later
menExit.Command = UICommands.CmdExit;
menExit.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(UICommands.CmdExit,     CmdExitExecute, CmdExitCanExecute));
menu.Items.Add(menExit);
```

It works very well with one exception. No matter what CmdExitCanExecute returns, the menu item shortcut is ALWAYS grayed out. Note that the text ("Exit") works as intended (grayed out when CmdExitCanExecute returns false and black when true) but not so the shortcut. To make matters more complicated: the shortcut works when I press the key combination. What do I need to do to make the shortcut show the right color? The menu is shown by right clicking a tray icon, but that shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: You didn't accept the answer below... did you find another solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is how the WPF default style works. If you actually disable a menu item, you will find that the shortcut text is a slightly lighter grey. The shortcut on a non-disabled item is slightly darker grey while the menu item text is black.
The difference is subtle and confusing but I think your MenuItem is working correctly.

Comment: The weird thing is that Visual Studio or Paint.NET are both in WPF and have a "normal" behavior, i.e. their shortcuts have discernible colors, just like every other desktop application on Earth. If the WPF team decided to depart from what's common to make such a decision, well...